# .htaccess Wordpress "Too many Redirects" error

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

Having an error after adding .htaccess redirects. Pages are getting the error "too many redirect loops". Pages which are not mentioned in the redirect list. No redirect plugins are being used.

- Yoast plugin is
  installed with the /category option enabled - removing category from URL. Error persists even when all plugins are disabled.

Some redirects work fine.

Having no luck! All plugins disabled - still not working. I believe it is WP's built-in redirect engine causing issues but I can't diagnose further or remove the WP 301 redirect "cache/history".

Thanks in advance!

**Domain**: https://cyced.co.uk

**Example of working redirect from the below list:**

https://cyced.co.uk/shropshire

**Example of a URL not in the list causing a redirect loop due to the below code:**

https://cyced.co.uk/blog/cycling-beginners-guide-how-to-start-biking-2018

.htaccess code in full:

```
redirect 301 /routes/gloucestershire-route/cheltenham-hillclimb-blitz-two-cycling-route /gloucestershire-cycling-routes
redirect 301 /routes/gloucestershire-route/gloucester-follow-severn-cycling-route /gloucestershire-cycling-routes
redirect 301 /routes/gloucestershire-route/gloucester-steady-cycling-route /gloucestershire-cycling-routes
redirect 301 /routes/gloucestershire-route/gloucestershire-campus-tour-cycling-route /gloucestershire-cycling-routes
redirect 301 /routes/gloucestershire-route/lechlade-cotswolds-cycling-route /gloucestershire-cycling-routes
redirect 301 /routes/gloucestershire-route/stroud-airfield-loop-cycling-route /gloucestershire-cycling-routes
redirect 301 /routes/gloucestershire-route/stroud-cycle-circuit-cycling-route /gloucestershire-cycling-routes
redirect 301 /routes/gloucestershire-route/stroud-newport-cycling-route /gloucestershire-cycling-routes
redirect 301 /routes/gloucestershire-route/forest-dean-newent-woods-cycling-route /gloucestershire-cycling-routes
redirect 301 /routes/gloucestershire-route/forest-dean-st-bravels-cycling-route /gloucestershire-cycling-routes
redirect 301 /routes/gloucestershire-route/cirencester-oxford-cycling-route /gloucestershire-cycling-routes
redirect 301 /routes/gloucestershire-route/cirencester-evesham-cycling-route /gloucestershire-cycling-routes
redirect 301 /routes/gloucestershire-route/cirencester-countryside-loop-cycling-route /gloucestershire-cycling-routes
redirect 301 /routes/gloucestershire-route/chipping-campden-bourton-water-cycling-route /gloucestershire-cycling-routes
redirect 301 /routes/gloucestershire-route/cheltenham-malvern-cycling-route /gloucestershire-cycling-routes
redirect 301 /routes/gloucestershire-route/cheltenham-bourton-water-cycling-route /gloucestershire-cycling-routes
redirect 301 /features/what-are-trail-dogs-and-adventure-dogs /cycling-blog
redirect 301 /shropshire /shropshire-hub
redirect 301 /south-wales /south-wales-hub
redirect 301 /gloucestershire /gloucestershire-hub
redirect 301 /blog /cycling-blog

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
# BEGIN WP-HUMMINGBIRD-GZIP

# END WP-HUMMINGBIRD-GZIP
# BEGIN WP-HUMMINGBIRD-CACHING

# END WP-HUMMINGBIRD-CACHING
```

[https configured in WP Dashbboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ekBb.png)

- URLs were changed recently to /blog hence the redirects. This was done by updating the category Slug in the WP dashboard.

Comment: Did you flush the cache? If you did, I think your database may still contains a lot of links with the old slug `/cycling-blog`, you can export the database, and use a text editor to search and replace the `/cycling-blog` to `/blog`, and re-import the database back. Remember to back up your database first prior do this.

Comment: alternatively if it is not too many posts, open each post one by one from WordPress admin, and check and edit each url manually to make sure it points to the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

With the details you showed over here we cannot be sure but as you can see, all content is doing fine but the content that is on your **blog/** directory is having a redirect problem.

You should review the code inside your **.htaccess** file inside your **blog/** directory and also see if there is any redirect command on the main files.

Comment: Hello,Wordpress is installed in the root. There is no second htacccess within /blog.

Thanks for taking the time though.

Comment: okay, well depending on the host, you can create another .htaccess on subdirectorys or a file named user.ini (it can change according to servers config) to customize configs in a specific directory without changing the root config